# Rails PUT method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, put, form-helpers

I am trying to use a put method to update a users (model) information.

The form is in a haml file and has different css so I dont want to use form_for construct.

However the request is hitting to create method although I pass a hidden input _method with value PUT as recommended for Rails.

Here is the code:

```
.create-profile-form
  %form.form-horizontal.border{action: '/users',type:'hidden', name:'_method', value:'put',method:'post'}
    / Form Name
    %h5.center title
    %br
    %br
    %br
    %br
    %legend.center Create Profile
    %br
    %br
    / Text input
    .form-group
```

The use case is:

1] User log's in using a social login. A user is already CREATEed at this step.

2] We take that information , pre-fill a form and also request additional information in the form. When user submits it UPDATEs the existing user.

Comment: You want to edit user information, right?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to actually create a hidden `%input` node with a `_method` value of `put`, nested under the `%form` node with method `post`:

```
%form.form-horizontal.border{action: '/users', method:'post'}
    %input{ type:'hidden', name:'_method', value:'put'}
...
```

I think combining all those attributes in your `%form` node was the issue (the `_method` with `put` attribute combined with the actual `method` attribute). As this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark) states, Rails understands the `put` method via a hidden ***input***, not a hidden ***form***.

See this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005882/631834) for more details about why you need to have a separate hidden `%input` tag with `hidden` and `_method` nested under a `%form` tag with `post` for `method`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the CSS stuff with your fields, still use form_for to generate your `<form>` tag, and then ignore helpers for your `<input>` fields. It will protect you from various vulnerabilities.

Also, Rails 4 tends to use PATCH instead of PUT as update HTTP verb.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use rails' form_for method?

```
.create-profile-form
  = form_for @user, url: '/users', class: 'form-horizontal border', method: :put do |f|
    # the rest
```

then the hidden field is created by rails and you can be sure it will work